# double function combination

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Suppose we have $f(x)=x$; and $g(x)=x^2$.

We know that $x$ and $x^2$ intersect at $(1,1)$. 
How to make a function $h$ that equals $f$ on $[0,1]$ and equals $g$ on $[1,\infty)$?

What will be the function $h(x)$ (for example) ?

Answer (score 1):

We can get $h(x)$ as function defined for cases:
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}-x^2\hspace{0,7cm}(-\infty,0)\\x\hspace{1,3cm} [0,1)\\x^2\hspace{1,1cm} [1,+\infty) \end{cases}$$

This is a continuous function for $x\in\mathbb R$, because $e(x)=-x^2$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ are continuos functions and $e(0)=f(0)=0$, $f(1)=g(1)=1$, thus they "stick" together to $x=0$ and $x=1$.